# Running PySpin (FLIR) Acquisition Example gives Error "module 'pyspin' has no attribute 'System'"

Tags: python, flir, spinnaker-cam

I'm trying to access the FLIR camera with the python SDK. Running the file "Acquisition" gives the following error: "module 'PySpin' has no attribute 'System'".

I tried searching online and the sources suggest that it's a naming error since there's another library named `pyspin` where the one we need is `PySpin` (Capital sensitive). I tried uninstalling `pyspin` installing `PySpin`, re-downloading the program as a whole, and making sure the wheel and python versions match, but nothing worked from what I've seen online.

What might be wrong?

Full Terminal message:

> none  File
> "c:\Users\blehe\Downloads\spinnaker_python-3.1.0.79-cp310-cp310-win\Examples\Python3\Acquisition.py",
> line 348, in 
> if main():   File "c:\Users\blehe\Downloads\spinnaker_python-3.1.0.79-cp310-cp310-win\Examples\Python3\Acquisition.py",
> line 298, in main
> system = PySpin.System.GetInstance() AttributeError: module 'PySpin' has no attribute 'System'

Comment: how were you installing/uninstalling these packages?  what's the actual output from Python, i.e. copy/paste the commands you're using and the output into the question (as text not screenshots).

Comment: I used pip to install and uninstall. The full message is as following:  File "c:\Users\blehe\Downloads\spinnaker_python-3.1.0.79-cp310-cp310-win\Examples\Python3\Acquisition.py", line 348, in <module>
    if main():
  File "c:\Users\blehe\Downloads\spinnaker_python-3.1.0.79-cp310-cp310-win\Examples\Python3\Acquisition.py", line 298, in main
    system = PySpin.System.GetInstance()
AttributeError: module 'PySpin' has no attribute 'System'

Comment: Edited just now

Comment: but what did you actually install and where?  computers are kind of pedantic so the details matter.  What do you get from evaluating `import PySpin; print(PySpin.__file__)` in Python?  What other files exist in the same directory as that file, does it look like the library you're expecting, or https://pypi.org/project/pyspin/?

Comment: I downloaded it in the downloads folder in the extracted folder which I downloaded from the website. Not sure I understood what you mean, but I'm trying to get the example to the example to work. In the directory there are other examples provided by FLIR. I think I downloaded the right "PySpin", not the terminal spinner.

Comment: That doesn't sound like you used pip to install it, and the directory name looks like you just extracted a wheel rather than installing it.  You should be able to run `python3 -m pip install wheel_file.whl` which might give you a properly installed package that functions as it's designed to

Comment: Just tried again says It's already installed: 
https://pastebin.com/WPnusncT

Comment: okay, that sounds good (note that it helps to include the commands and output like that in the question, the vague descriptions you have suggest other issues).  does the output from `print(PySpin.__file__)` also start with `c:\users\blehe\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages`?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean but after entering it in the terminal I got the following message: https://pastebin.com/dm68f2Lc. Thank you so much!

Comment: you need to import the module first (as I pointed out in the earlier comment!)  it might be worth spending some time going through some basic Python tutorials if this is confusing, I'm deliberately not using any fancy tools to keep things easy but I do assume you have some familiarity with the language you're trying to use

Comment: I see. Final silly question please: to import the module I need to install the wheel file and "import PySpin" in my code? Because I've done that, I'm guessing that's not what you mean though. 

Thank you so much anyhow!

Comment: as far as I understand you already have the package installed, you just need to run `import PySpin` in the same Python REPL as you're running the `print` statement from.  spending some time with just the  builtin Python functionality (i.e. before complicating things with installing packages) would likely help a lot

Comment: It can help to explain what was wrong and what you did to fix it in an answer.  If you think you can explain it in a way that is likely to benefit people in a similar situation…